# git pull, git reset HEAD <new_files_from_pull> , git push. Why are those new_files_from_pull in pull request?

Tags: git

1. I did a `git pull` and I got new files after that.
2. I saw those new files in "Changes to be committed:" list when I did a `git status`. So I did `git reset HEAD <new_file_from_pull>` for all new files that I got. I ensured with `git status` that I have only my old
   files are in "Changes to be committed:" list.
3. I did a `git push origin <my_branch>` and now both the new files which were not under that  "Changes to be committed:" list and my old files which were under  "Changes to be committed:" list  got pushed. Why is that and how can I recover from it? I at least want to know if this is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Git is most likely telling you what happened. Please add git output you got after each commands.

Comment: I at least want to know if this is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: If you have new file(s) to commit after a `pull`, you clearly overlooked git output. Most of the time it is telling you what you can do to finalize the `pull`. If you want help with that, please provide initial `git pull` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, lesson learnt is to make sure for any command you execute there is a message and you read it. I observed that 
`git commit -m <your message>` will not give complete details on all the files that were/are going to be committed.
So, first do 
`git commit` then you will see the actual files that are going to be committed. Read and make sure you have exactly the files that you want to commit, no less, no more.
Then you can add comments and do `wq` as in vi editor. If you don't want to commit then simply do :`q` as in vi editor to cancel you commit process.